# Remove array item and updating array index

Tags: python

How would I go about removing an array item from an array in a way that keeps the array index in an incremental list?

Basically I want to do this:

Modify the following array so that it results in the next one

```
#before
arrayName[0] = "asdf random text"
arrayName[1] = "more randomasdf"
arrayName[2] = "this is the array item i am about to remove"
arrayName[3] = "another asdfds"
arrayName[4] = "and som easdf"

#after
arrayName[0] = "asdf random text"
arrayName[1] = "more randomasdf"
arrayName[2] = "another asdfds"
arrayName[3] = "and som easdf"
```

Notice how arrayName[2] from the #before array is gone in the #after array and the index has been reordered so that arrayName[3] from the #before array is now arrayName[2].

I want to delete the array item and reorder the array index.

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: I'm guessing by "array" you mean a plain Python `list`, right?  (There is no built-in data type called "array" in Python, but there is an `array` module in the standard library.  And some people use "array" in the context of Python to refer to NumPy arrays without explicitly saying so.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "array" you actually mean "list", you can simply use `del`:

```
del arrayName[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = ["asdf random text", "more randomasdf", "this is the array item i am about to remove", "another asdfds", "and som easdf",]
>>> a
['asdf random text', 'more randomasdf', 'this is the array item i am about to remove', 'another asdfds', 'and som easdf']
>>> a.pop(2)
'this is the array item i am about to remove'
>>> a
['asdf random text', 'more randomasdf', 'another asdfds', 'and som easdf']
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the **del** command

```
del(arrayName[2])
```

python will automatically re-order it for you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is a python list,you can try `del arrayName[2]` or `arrayName.pop(2)`. The complexity of each deletion is O(N), N is the length of the list.

If the arrayName's length or the number of the indexes you want to delete is really large,you may try this.

```
indexestodelete = set(2,.....)
arrayName[:] = [arrayName[index] for index not in indexestodelete ]
```